# Get variable from client-side JavaScript file in Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to send a variable from my client-side JavaScript file to my server-side app.js file. I know that you can get a value from something like a form input field using methods such as the one below (using Express):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

let cityResponse;

app.post('/city', function(req,res) {
  cityResponse = {
    user_name: req.body.userName
  }
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/city/index.html'));
});
```

But I would like to get a value not directly from the HTML, but from the JavaScript file that the HTML is attached to.

---

As well as this, I am currently using Socket.io to send the data from the server to the client, and vice versa, using a `window.onload` to let the server know when the page is ready:

**index.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
  socket.emit('cityPageReady');
  console.log("city page ready");
};

socket.on('cityPageInfo', function(cityResponse) {
  console.log('city page info received');
  console.log(cityResponse);
  console.log(cityResponse.user_name);
  userName = cityResponse.user_name;
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = userName;
});
```

**app.js**

```
var city = io.of('/city').on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A user has connected!');
  socket.on('cityPageReady', function() {
    socket.emit('cityPageInfo', cityResponse);
    console.log('city page ready recieved');
  });
});
```

This works, but many people have said that this is overkill, or as one person put it, "using a hammer to kill a bee". Ideally, I'd like to use the optimal method. I do know that template engines can achieve this, but I do not want to have to rewrite all my HTML just to be able to send a single variable to the server.

---

To reiterate, my questions are:

- How would I get a variable from the client-side JavaScript file (not the HTML)?
- What is the best way to send these variables back over to client-side?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Should I consider learning something like React or Angular instead? (I think that's what they do.)" — It isn't. They are essentially client-side templates + a massive amount of stuff to handle URLs, ajax and data management. Massively more complicated than just using a server-side template.

Comment: @Quentin Ah. Well, I'll edit that out then.